How to create a type-token ratio table in R based on two tables?
I have two tables. One is the table of the token frequency:



AUX
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21




toss
0
0
0
20
47
16
38
11
28


shoot
0
0
0
0
3
0
1
1
3


launch
32
15
101
153
95
40
500
500
500


throw
0
0
0
0
0
0
55
125
500


pull
0
0
2
0
0
8
0
7
81



The other is a table for the type frequency:



AUX
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21




toss
0
0
0
16
34
13
32
10
27


shoot
0
0
0
0
2
0
1
1
3


launch
8
3
15
12
12
17
18
22
20


throw
0
0
0
0
0
0
44
95
215


pull
0
0
7
0
0
7
0
7
46



Desired output: type-token



AUX
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21




toss
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.80
0.72
0.81
0.84
0.91
0.96


shoot
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.67
0.00
1.00
1.00
1.00


launch
0.25
0.20
0.15
0.08
0.13
0.43
0.04
0.04
0.04


throw
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.80
0.76
0.43


pull
0.00
0.00
1.00
0.00
0.00
0.88
0.00
1.00
0.57



How can I create a table of type-token ratio with R? I would prefer a tidyverse version. Thank you.

If the rows and columns exactly match as shown in this example then df2[-1]/df1[-1] should do it.

Thank you! And how can I replace "NaN" with 0 (zero)?

Something like library(dplyr); tibble(AUX = d1[,1], d2[,-1] / d1[,-1]) %>% mutate(across(-AUX, ~ replace(.x, is.nan(.x), 0))).

Thank you! I did tibble(AUX = token[,1], type[,-1] / token[,-1]) %>% mutate(across(-AUX, ~ replace(.x, is.nan(.x), 0))) but got an error message:
Error in [<-.data.frame(tmp, , j, value = c(“# A tibble: 5 × 1”, :    Replacement has 9 lines, data has 5 Calls: .main ... replace_na -> to_character -> [<- -> [<-.data.frame

If I do df2[-1]/df1[-1] the left column (AUX) doesn't appear (which I actually need to create the desired output). That's probably why I got the error message.

One possible way to solve your problem:
cols = names(Filter(is.numeric, df1))  # get numaric column names

df3 = df1
df3[cols] = Map(\(x,y) ifelse(x!=0, y/x, 0), df1[cols], df2[cols])
           
     AUX   13  14        15         16        17     18        19        20        21
1   toss 0.00 0.0 0.0000000 0.80000000 0.7234043 0.8125 0.8421053 0.9090909 0.9642857
2  shoot 0.00 0.0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.6666667 0.0000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
3 launch 0.25 0.2 0.1485149 0.07843137 0.1263158 0.4250 0.0360000 0.0440000 0.0400000
4  throw 0.00 0.0 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000 0.8000000 0.7600000 0.4300000
5   pull 0.00 0.0 3.5000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.8750 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.5679012

data
df1 = structure(list(AUX = c("toss", "shoot", "launch", "throw", "pull"
), `13` = c(0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 0L), `14` = c(0L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 0L
), `15` = c(0L, 0L, 101L, 0L, 2L), `16` = c(20L, 0L, 153L, 0L, 
0L), `17` = c(47L, 3L, 95L, 0L, 0L), `18` = c(16L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 
8L), `19` = c(38L, 1L, 500L, 55L, 0L), `20` = c(11L, 1L, 500L, 
125L, 7L), `21` = c(28L, 3L, 500L, 500L, 81L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 = structure(list(AUX = c("toss", "shoot", "launch", "throw", "pull"
), `13` = c(0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L), `14` = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L), 
    `15` = c(0L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 7L), `16` = c(16L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 
    0L), `17` = c(34L, 2L, 12L, 0L, 0L), `18` = c(13L, 0L, 17L, 
    0L, 7L), `19` = c(32L, 1L, 18L, 44L, 0L), `20` = c(10L, 1L, 
    22L, 95L, 7L), `21` = c(27L, 3L, 20L, 215L, 46L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))


After a lot of headaches, I finally solved the problem:
tibble(AUX = df1[, 1], df2[, -1] / df1[, -1]) |> mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 0) |> round(digits = 2)))
Na is replaced with 0 (zero) only where the column is numeric. No error message now. And I can add the function round, as the desired output should have digits = 2.
